# Confusing "std::out_of_range" Error

Tags: c++, stdstring

I've been debugging this error for the last 2 hours, and knowing myself I won't be able to sleep if I don't ask for help before I go to bed. I'm writing a model loader for my game, and just for now I'm using a pretty flimsy method to split strings. However, it works on nearly identical lines, then randomly doesn't. I'm using string.substr(), and I believe the error means its trying to start at a location that doesn't exist in the string. The call stack says its happening on this line:

```
v1 = v1.substr(s.find(",")+1);
```

and by using a breakpoint that prints a message, it says

> Vertex 1 is using "1,1" and the entire string is "173,1,1 175,1,1
>   174,1,1"

where Vertex 1 is the value of v1, and string is the value of s.

This is the entire function:

```
FaceData data;
s = s.substr(5); //remove "FACE "
string v1, v2, v3;

//vertex 1
v1 = s.substr(0, s.find(" "));

data.vertexIndexes[0] = atoi(v1.substr(0, s.find(",")).c_str());
v1 = v1.substr(s.find(",")+1);
data.textureIndexes[0] = atoi(v1.substr(0, s.find(",")).c_str());
v1 = v1.substr(s.find(",")+1);
data.normalIndexes[0] = atoi(v1.c_str());

//vertex 2
s = s.substr(s.find(" ")+1);
v2 = s.substr(0, s.find(" "));

data.vertexIndexes[1] = atoi(v2.substr(0, s.find(",")).c_str());
v2 = v2.substr(s.find(",")+1);
data.textureIndexes[1] = atoi(v2.substr(0, s.find(",")).c_str());
v2 = v2.substr(s.find(",")+1);
data.normalIndexes[1] = atoi(v2.c_str());

//vertex 3
s = s.substr(s.find(" ")+1);
v3 = s;

data.vertexIndexes[2] = atoi(v3.substr(0, s.find(",")).c_str());
v3 = v3.substr(s.find(",")+1);
data.textureIndexes[2] = atoi(v3.substr(0, s.find(",")).c_str());
v3 = v3.substr(s.find(",")+1);
data.normalIndexes[2] = atoi(v3.c_str());

return data;
```

the std::string 's' being passed to the function always looks like this:
"FACE X,X,X X,X,X X,X,X"
where x is a number.

This is the only way I could find to split a string...

Now, I don't understand why it is getting this error here... It seems like it's almost just happening randomly. I can't understand why it won't work with

> 173,1,1 175,1,1 174,1,1

but it will work with

> 175,2,2 176,2,2 175,2,2

Comment: You will probably have to paste more source before someone will be able to spot the problem.

Comment: Please try to create a [Short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Just guessing here, but if you have a string like `hi,` the `+1` might be asking `substr` to start at an invalid location.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I don't know what I even meant by the garbage I wrote at the end... but I added more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm interpreting your question correctly, but given the information you provided, this seems to be what you're doing:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string v1 = "1,1";
    std::string s = "173,1,1 175,1,1 174,1,1";

    try {
        v1 = v1.substr(s.find(",")+1);
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
        std::cout << "out_of_range: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In that case, `s.find(",")` will return `3` (the first `,` in `s` is at position 3), however since `v1` only has three characters the only valid indexes are between `[0,2]`. Passing in `3`, or with the `+1` `4` would be out of range for `v1`.

Comment: Based on your latest code sample, I'd look into why you're finding "," in s instead of in v1. Since you're taking a substring of v1, it seems like your search for a starting character should be against that variable as well.