# C++ Visual Studio out of range error

Tags: visual-c++

I seem to be having an issue similar to the post here: [Confusing "std::out_of_range" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549338/confusing-stdout-of-range-error) . My problem is I can't figure out where/how I need to fix the issue. Here is my code, and I'll post the error beneath.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
//In this program we are going to make a secret code decoder.
int main() {
    /*char a = '!';
    char b = '^';
    char c = '&';
    char d = '*';   
    char e = '@';
    char f = '(';
    char g = ')';
    char h = '-';
    char i = '#';
    char j = '_';
    char k = '=';
    char l = '+';
    char m = '[';
    char n = '{';
    char o = '$';
    char p = ']';
    char q = '}';
    char r = ';';
    char s = ':';
    char t = ',';
    char u = '%';
    char v = '<';
    char w = '.';
    char x = '>';
    char y = '/';
    char z = '?';*/

    // Now for the tedious part... declaring variables for the 26 letters of the alphabet, and searching the string and replacing... :p

    int A = 0;
    int B = 0;
    int C = 0;
    int D = 0;
    int E = 0;
    int F = 0;
    int G = 0;
    int H = 0;
    int I = 0;
    int J = 0;
    int K = 0;
    int L = 0;
    int M = 0;
    int N = 0;
    int O = 0;
    int P = 0;
    int Q = 0;
    int R = 0;
    int S = 0;
    int T = 0;
    int U = 0;
    int V = 0;
    int W = 0;
    int X = 0;
    int Y = 0;
    int Z = 0;

    // Now getting the code itself.
    string toDecode = "";
    cout << "Enter code: ";
    cin >> toDecode;
    cout << endl;

    //Now I should be searching the code that was entered to find my various symbols.
    A = toDecode.find('!');
        if (A != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('!', 1, 'a');
        return 0;
    }
    B = toDecode.find('^');
        if (B != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('^', 1, 'b');
        return 0;
   }
    C = toDecode.find('&');
    if (C != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('&', 1, 'c');
        return 0;
    }
    D = toDecode.find('*');
    if (D != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('*', 1, 'd');
        return 0;
    }
    E = toDecode.find('@');
    if (E != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('@', 1, 'e');
        return 0;
    }
    F = toDecode.find('(');
    if (F != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('(', 1, 'f');
        return 0;
    }
    G = toDecode.find(')');
    if (G != -1) {
        toDecode.insert(')', 1, 'g');
        return 0;
    }
    H = toDecode.find('-');
    if (H != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('-', 1, 'h');
        return 0;
    }
    I = toDecode.find('#');
    if (I != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('#', 1, 'i');
        return 0;
    }
    J = toDecode.find('_');
    if (J != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('_', 1, 'j');
        return 0;
    }
    K = toDecode.find('=');
    if (K != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('=', 1, 'k');
        return 0;
    }
    L = toDecode.find('+');
    if (L != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('+', 1, 'l');
        return 0;
    }
    M = toDecode.find('[');
    if (M != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('[', 1, 'm');
        return 0;
    }
    N = toDecode.find('{');
    if (N != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('{', 1, 'n');
        return 0;
    }
    O = toDecode.find('$');
    if (O != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('$', 1, 'o');
        return 0;
    }
    P = toDecode.find(']');
    if (P != -1) {
        toDecode.insert(']', 1, 'p');
        return 0;
    }
    Q = toDecode.find('}');
    if (Q != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('}', 1, 'q');
        return 0;
    }
    R = toDecode.find(';');
    if (R != -1) {
        toDecode.insert(';', 1, 'r');
        return 0;
    }
    S = toDecode.find(':');
    if (S != -1) {
       toDecode.insert(':', 1, 's');
       return 0;
    }
    T = toDecode.find(',');
    if (T != -1) {
        toDecode.insert(',', 1, 't');
        return 0;
    }
    U = toDecode.find('%');
    if (U != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('%', 1, 'u');
        return 0;
    }
    V = toDecode.find('<');
    if (V != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('<', 1, 'v');
        return 0;
    }
    W = toDecode.find('.');
    if (W != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('.', 1, 'w');
        return 0;
    }
    X = toDecode.find('>');
    if (X != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('>', 1, 'x');
        return 0;
    }
    Y = toDecode.find('/');
    if (Y != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('/', 1, 'y');
        return 0;
    }
    Z = toDecode.find('?');
    if (Z != -1) {
        toDecode.insert('?', 1, 'z');
        return 0;
    }

    string beenDecoded = "";
    /*Now at this point, we need to be able to identify the code when we see it. Let's use the space and type it all out here:
    '!' ­> 'a'
    '^' ­> 'b'
    '&' ­> 'c'
    '*' ­> 'd'
    '@' ­> 'e'
    '(' ­> 'f'
    ')' ­> 'g'
    '-­' ­> 'h'
    '#' ­> 'i'
    '_' ­> 'j'
    '=' ­> 'k'
    '+' ­> 'l'
    '[' ­> 'm'
    '{' ­> 'n'
    '$' ­> 'o'
    ']' ­> 'p'
    '}' ­> 'q'
    '?' ­> 'r'
    ':' ­> 's'
    ',' ­> 't'
    '%' ­> 'u'
    '<' ­> 'v'
    '.' ­> 'w'
    '>' ­> 'x'
    '/' ­> 'y'
    '?' ­> 'z'
    */
    // Now we have our code. Let's declare a variable for each of those, and set them to equal.

    // Let's get the message printed:

    cout << toDecode << endl;



    return 0;

}
```

**Now for the error:**

```
// exception handling support functions
#include <new>
#include <stdexcept>

_STD_BEGIN
_CRTIMP2_PURE _NO_RETURN(__CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Xbad_alloc())
    {   // report a bad_alloc error

    _THROW_NCEE(_XSTD bad_alloc, _EMPTY_ARGUMENT);

    }

_CRTIMP2_PURE _NO_RETURN(__CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Xinvalid_argument(_In_z_ const char *_Message))
    {   // report an invalid_argument error
    _THROW_NCEE(invalid_argument, _Message);
    }

 _CRTIMP2_PURE _NO_RETURN(__CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Xlength_error(_In_z_ const char *_Message))
    {   // report a length_error
    _THROW_NCEE(length_error, _Message);
    }

_CRTIMP2_PURE _NO_RETURN(__CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Xout_of_range(_In_z_ const char *_Message))
    {   // report an out_of_range error
    _THROW_NCEE(out_of_range, _Message);
    }

_CRTIMP2_PURE _NO_RETURN(__CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Xoverflow_error(_In_z_ const char *_Message))
    {   // report an overflow error
    _THROW_NCEE(overflow_error, _Message);
    }

_CRTIMP2_PURE _NO_RETURN(__CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Xruntime_error(_In_z_ const char *_Message))
    {   // report a runtime_error
    _THROW_NCEE(runtime_error, _Message);
    }
_STD_END

 #include <functional>

_STD_BEGIN
_CRTIMP2_PURE _NO_RETURN(__CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Xbad_function_call())
    {   // report a bad_function_call error
    _THROW_NCEE(bad_function_call, _EMPTY_ARGUMENT);
    }
_STD_END

#if _HAS_EXCEPTIONS
#include <regex>

_STD_BEGIN
_CRTIMP2_PURE _NO_RETURN(__CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL             _Xregex_error(regex_constants::error_type _Code))
    {   // report a regex_error
    _THROW_NCEE(regex_error, _Code);
    }
_STD_END
#endif /* _HAS_EXCEPTIONS */
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire code looks like you want something else to happen when you call insert() function, may be a replace of a character with other!!!?

As John rightly mentioned, none of the insert() functions take first param as character, they are position (int or iterators) on which you want to insert a character or string. Your all calls to insert() takes first param as a character which gives the ascii value of it to position parameter of the insert() function, hence you get out of range error.

Refer the syntax of insert() here [string::insert()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/)

```
string& insert (size_t pos, const string& str); 
string& insert (size_t pos, const string& str, size_t subpos, size_t sublen); 
string& insert (size_t pos, const char* s); 
string& insert (size_t pos, const char* s, size_t n); fill (5)    string& insert (size_t pos, size_t n, char c);
void insert (iterator p, size_t n, char c); 
insert (iterator p, char c); 
void insert (iterator p, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

As I said earlier, it looks like insert() is not the function you are expecting to be there for your purpose. Are you looking for replace()ing the character. Then use,

```
string& replace (size_t pos,  size_t len,  size_t n, char c);
```

Then again, this function needs position as first parameter. Something like this,

```
A = toDecode.find('!');
        if (A != -1) {
        toDecode.replace(A, 1,1,'a');
        return 0;
    }
```

The above replace(A,1,1,'a') function call will replace the first occurrence of '!' character on the string with 'a'.

Remember, in replace() function, first param is position, if this exceeds the length of string you will get out_of_range. Second param is number of characters to replace, third is number of times to copy the character and fourth is the character you want to place in the string.

**Update #1:**
After looking into your code bit further, what I understand is, you are actually trying to replace "!^&*@()-#_=+[{$]};:,%<.>/?" characters with "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" characters. Your "return 0" on every if condition will anyway spoil that. I don't know why you wrote that way. However, on the whole, the program can be simple like this,

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string actual("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    string codes ("!^&*@()-#_=+[{$]};:,%<.>/?");
    string toDecode ="";
    cout << "Enter code:";          // get the string to decode
    cin >> toDecode;
    cout <<endl;
    // find the code chars in the entered string
    size_t found = toDecode.find_first_of(codes);
    // loop through all the found code characters
    while(found!=std::string::npos)
    {
        // get the position of the found code character in string "codes"
        // the same position character in string actual is the decoded char
        size_t cpos=codes.find(toDecode[found]);
        // assign the decoded char to the code char. Eg: '!'='a'
        toDecode[found]=actual[cpos];
        // Look for the next code character
        found = toDecode.find_first_of(codes);
    }
    cout << toDecode;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great! That solved the errors. Now I execute the code, and as soon as I enter whatever I want to translate, it runs without errors, but it just exits without displaying anything. @Naren Neelamegam Do you need me to post the modified code?

Comment: "return 0" on every if condition makes your program to exit after replacing the character. Updated the answer with a simple way of doing it. Please check. Also, please refer to C++ function references to get better idea of how to use them efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

No std::string insert() take parameters char, int, char so your chars are being promoted to ints and since your string is empty  - perhaps you meant replace instead of insert?

I'm guessing it ends up calling `insert (size_t pos, size_t n, char c);`. Another hint is if using insert you need `str = str.insert(...);`

Comment: Can you give me an example of  " take parameters char, int, char" , I'm not sure what you are saying.

Comment: You call `toDecode.insert('!', 1, 'a');` which doesn't do what you expect. It tries to insert 1 'a' at position 33 of the string (because '!' is decimal 33). The string doesn't have a position 33.